# How can convert an array of jsons to a json object?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I did some changes to an specific part of a json, an array to be more specific, to finish I want to save the changes in the json, but I can't because xcode give me this error:

> "Cannot assign value of type '[JSON]' to type 'JSON'"

This is a sample of the code:

```
let originalSessionJson = dataObject!.sessionJson
var json:[JSON] = originalSessionJson["activity"].arrayValue

for i in 0 ..< json.count{
 .
 .
 .
}
dataObject?.sessionJson["activity"] = json
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean this:

dataObject?.sessionJson["activity"].arrayObject = json

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, it's giving me another error, it says...
"Cannot assign value of type [JSON] to type [AnyObject]?", JSON it's not any object?, or i have to someway cast it?